# 'compass watch' does not regenerate css inside vagrant

Tags: compass-sass, vagrant

I have a simple html project inside vagrant in which I want to use Compass to handle css. But running the `compass watch` command inside the project folder in vagrant does not regenerate the css file on changing the sass(.scss) file.

It will however regenerate if I do a Ctrl-C and then run `compass watch` again.

a. I read this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/107 and I have updated my cache-dir to '../../tmp/sass-cache'

b. I am not running a rails app, just compass to generate css.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to run `compass watch --poll`.

I had the same problem in Vagrant and this worked for me.

Comment: Any idea why this fixes it? This didn't work for me, vagrant is still not recognizing the changed css. but just trying to understand the general issue

Comment: works for me! maybe some bug fixes happened in latest updates: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/394

Comment: Works for me too. Strange problem. I would like to understand why. I am using Vagrant and Wordpress.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by not using a symlinked directory.